# Проблема установки canvas node.js

Tags: node.js

При попытке установить модуль canvas

`var canvas = require("canvas")`

Происходит ошибка

`Uncaught Error: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.
 \\?\C:\Users\zzz\Desktop\Бот\pocket 2.0\node_modules\canvas\build\Release\canvas.`

Comment: Может зависимостей не хватает? Попробуйте сами скомпилировать.

Comment: @ReklatsMasters а как это делается?